# Python mechanize is not handling form exception

Tags: python, exception, mechanize

I am writing a web scraper using Python and mechanize. The scraper looks for the "Next" button and loops until it comes to the last page, which does not have a "Next" button. That gives the FormNotFoundError: exception, which stops the loop. When I try to catch the exception, I get a NameError: instead of the actual error. 
What am I doing wrong? 
Alternatively, is there a better way to stop the loop when I have reached the end?

Here is the relevant code.

```
Import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://example.com")
x=0        
while x > 1:
    try:
        br.select_form(nr=2) 
        response = br.submit("next")
        *otherstuff*
    except FormNotFoundError:
        break
```

Here is the error output.

```
  File "scraping.py", line 32, in <module>
    except FormNotFoundError:
NameError: name 'FormNotFoundError' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change this to:

```
except mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError:
```

instead of this:

```
except FormNotFoundError:
```